# Why is NLog not logging scope data to Application Insights custom Dimensions

Tags: c#, scope, azure-application-insights, nlog, custom-dimensions

I am currently logging to Application Insights using NLog configured in an nlog.config file. I don't have `IncludeScopes` set anywhere (it is true by default).

I am trying to log custom properties using scope. It works when logging to a file or the console but not when logging to the Application Insights customDimensions.

This is how I am logging my scope:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["ActivityId"] = Guid.NewGuid()})
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Logging from with scope");
}
```

and this is the nlog.config file:

```xml
<target name="applicationInsights" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" >
    <instrumentationKey>8d9f67d5-fe36-45cf-935f-2f87bb240b12</instrumentationKey>
    <!-- Only required if not using ApplicationInsights.config -->
    <contextproperty name="threadId" layout="${threadid}" />
    <contextproperty name="processName" layout="${processname}" />
    <!-- Can be repeated with more context -->
</target>
```

Unfortunately I don't see the ActivityId when I look in the customDimensions in Application Insights.

I am running my Console app in Azure so have registered a worker service (which processes messages) like this:

```
services.AddHostedService<PositionMessageProcessor>()
```

What do I need to do get the logging scope to log my ActivityId in Application Insights?

**Update**

I have managed to it logging the ActivityId by adding it as a specific `contextProperty`. I don't really want to have to update the config file everytime I call `BeginScope(...)` with different properties.

Is there a generic way to get it to work for **all** scope properties?

Comment: Have this waiting: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/2103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a generic way to get it to work for all scope properties?

I assume you mean that it sends all the scoped properties to application insights without specifying which keys.

Currently this isn't supported by the target, see [source](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/9137120a096459af10c67503131a3202f42e084c/LOGGING/src/NLogTarget/ApplicationInsightsTarget.cs).

In NLog 4, the scope properties are pushed to the [`NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.htm).

You could do that by creating your own target:

1. Copy the target from [source](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/9137120a096459af10c67503131a3202f42e084c/LOGGING/src/NLogTarget/ApplicationInsightsTarget.cs)
2. Loop over `NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.GetAllObjects()` in `BuildPropertyBag` inside `ApplicationInsightsTarget`.
3. Register your target, see [NLog-Register your custom component](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component)

Comment: This will only work if using `TargetWithContext`. See also https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/pull/2103

Answer (score 1):

You can have scope-context included as blob-data by using a `<contextproperty>` with a [JsonLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout):

```
<target type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget">
        <contextProperty name="scopeproperties">
            <layout type="JsonLayout" includeMdlc="true" />
        </contextProperty/>
</target>
```